# (Java) How would you write a program that counts the number of times it runs and stores that number?

Tags: java

Say the user runs SomeProgram.java to calculate a bunch of stuff. One of the things they want to keep track of is how many times this program has been run and output the current run number. This is how far I got but it resets each time.

```
public class SomeProgram
{
    public volatile int counter = 1;

    public int getNextRun()
    {
        return counter++;
    }

    //calculates a bunch of variable that get output to user
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SomeProgram variable = new SomeProgram();
        runNumber = variable.getNextRun();
        System.out.println(runNumber + "Some bunch of calculations");
    }
}
```

Can someone explain why this got downvoted?

Comment: So you want to keep the counter between application starts?

Comment: It depends on what you need it for. If it's just for information, you can simply save it in a file and at each start read the value back, increment it and save it again. It isn't perfect but it doesn't have to be. However if the count is for licensing purposes, things get a lot trickier. A big lot.

Comment: Static variable? increases the number when a method called

Comment: you want to know how many times it has been called since the JVM has been started or you want an all time value?

Comment: no its not homework, or a license, its just for me and my coworkers, it keeps track of the number of runs we do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete implementation which stores updated counter in a file, invoke it whenever you want a counter to increment (i.e. when program starts). When a file doesn't exist, it is created. This method returns updated counter or 0 if there was some `IOException`.

```
public static int updateCounter() {

    String counterFileName = "counter.txt";

    int counter = 0;

    File counterFile = new File(counterFileName); 
    if (counterFile.isFile()) {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(counterFileName))) {         
            counter = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }
    }

    try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(counterFileName)) {     
        writer.write(String.valueOf(++counter));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }

    return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the user *stops* running your program, you're going to lose any variables stored in memory, so you're going to have to store that value somewhere else. The easiest solution would be to store it in a local file.

If your business needs to know this number, you can have the program call home to a webserver every time it starts up - this prevents the user from modifying the file on their computer - but is far more complicated to set up, and some users might not appreciate this unexpected behavior.

Comment: Not to mention that a naive implementation of such a mechanism takes about 5 minutes of effort to fool.

Answer (score 0):

Writing to the local file is not a good idea. You'll have to implement locking mechanism on your local file, otherwise you'll suffer of race conditions in case of simultaneous start of several program instances.

Alternative idea is to log each run into a persistent storage. So if you write each run's date and time to the db, you'll be able to calculate number of runs for arbitrary time interval.

Actual implementation depends on your requirements

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Properties file:

```
public void loadProperties(String fileName) 
    {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        InputStream is = null;   
        // First try loading from the current directory
        try {
            File f = new File(fileName);
            is = new FileInputStream( f );
        }catch ( Exception e ) {
            is = null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            if ( is == null ) {
                // Try loading from classpath
                is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("example.properties");
            }    
            // Try loading properties from the file (if found)
            props.load( is );
            String counter1 = props.getProperty("COUNTER_RUN");
            String counter2 = props.getProperty("COUNTER_OUTPUT");
            counterRun = Integer.parseInt(counter1);
            counterOutput =  = Integer.parseInt(counter2);
        }catch ( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

public void saveProperties(String fileName) {
      try { 
           Properties props = new Properties();
           props.setProperty("COUNTER_RUN", ""+counterRun );
           props.setProperty("COUNTER_OUTPUT", ""+counterOutput );
           File f = new File(fileName); 
           OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( f ); 
           props.store(out, "Config params"); 
       } catch (Exception e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
```

counterRun and counterOutput are global vars

File example.properties

```
#Config paramns
#Tue May 03 14:17:35 COT 2016
COUNTER_RUN=241
COUNTER_OUTPUT=123
```

Comment: but that doesn't update the properties file every time the program is run

Comment: in the next answer can view the save method

Comment: edit your answer and include both, you may give 2 answers but you shouldn't give 2x half of one.